# How to concat videos from a file list while adding black fade transitions in ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have a piece of code that concats videos from a file list. It works perfectly.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file_list.txt -c copy mergedVideo.avi
```

However, I want to add a black fade transition between each video. I found this code snippet that apparently does this, but it requires you to input each file by hand.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i main.mp4 -i out.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]fade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=28,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
   [1:v]fade=type=in:duration=2,fade=type=out:duration=2:start_time=28,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
   [2:v]fade=type=in:duration=2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
   [v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

I want to be able to read all the video files from a txt file as I have hundreds of videos. How do I combine these two snippets, or is there a better way to accomplish the concat with fade transitions?

Comment: Do it in 2 stages (easy to do in Python). Run FFmpeg once to fade each video (to a temp output file) then use `-f concat / -c copy` the outputs together. If you have hundreds of videos, this will most likely be the most efficient solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an easy way to do this?